# Mapping nested objects (java)

Tags: java, mapping, dto

I have some nested objects. Let's call them A, B and C.

```
public class A  {
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    //......{some other fields}
    private List<B> bList;
}

public class B  {
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    //......{some other fields}
    private List<C> cList;
}


public class C  {
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    ......{some other fields}
}
```

Now I want to map only some properties of those objects. Let's say I want only name and list of B from A, only list of C from B and only desc from C.
So I create DTO objects.

```
public class ADTO{
    private String name;
    List<BDTO> bList;
}

public class BDTO{
    List<CDTO> cList;
}

public class CDTO{
    private String desc;
}
```

And I would manually map A to ADTO, B to BDTO, and C to CDTO with code similar to this:

```
private ADTO map(A a)
     ADTO adto = new ADTO();
     List<BDTO> bDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
     adto.setName(a.getName());
     for (B b : a.getBlist()){
        BDTO bdto = new BDTO();
        bdto.setCList = map(b.getCList());
        bDTOList.add(bdto);
    }
    adto.setBList(bDTOList);
    return adto;
}
private List<CDTO> map(List<C>){
........ANOTHER BORING MAPPING
}
```

Is there any easier way (some design pattern maybe) to implement such task? Imagine what would happen if we have much larger classes or more objects on them to map with deeper nesting. It is a lot of code to write only to show/hide some fields.
P.S. I will need to write at least 3 different "views" of such object and the numbers of "views" can increase in the future. So I'm looking for solution to add new "view" more easily in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try this open source project [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) its targeting this Problem and make it easier.